# Are the Vox Populi and Suffrage badges good for a profile or not?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta

I am using Stack Overflow, and I want to earn badges. I was looking at the list of badges available on Stack Overflow, and I caught the two badges [Vox Populi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732) and [Suffrage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732).

Are these good for my profile or not? I mean do they help to make a user profile more impressive?

Comment: What do you mean by "good"?

Comment: means are they make impressive to any user profile ?

Comment: These badges are good if you earn them without upvoting every random question on the front page.

Comment: @ M.A.R. how any one knows that he earn these from upvoting randown question or  not ?

Comment: There are some people that cheat by just upvoting everything in their reach to get those and other vote-related badges. I'm asking, no, begging you, not to be one of those. Read the post carefully before casting your vote on it, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's always a good idea to use your votes wisely for things that deserve it, and as with anything, hunting for badges for badges sake can sometimes be a tiny bit dangerous.

All those badges show that you voted lots on a day (and you should always vote appropriately!) and are unlikely to make you smarter, better looking or richer.

Most badges are more for "Ooh, I/he did this" than any practical purpose. They're no different from steam achievements.

So, use the site as you'd use the site anyway, and if you see enough good stuff (or terrible stuff that needs downvotes), rejoice!.

Comment: but if we vote for deserving one then i don't think so this is possible to earn these 2 badges as it is hard to do 40 votes for deserving one in a day

Comment: Done it on SU. SO has so much volume - so it should be easier. Think about it this way - can you find 40 posts that made you go "Oh, this is useful?" I'm  sure its possible.

Answer (score 4):

No. Vox Populi and Suffrage require you vote, nothing more. You can get them by blindly clicking buttons for a couple minutes (definitely don't do that though)...

You can game most badges so I don't see how any are really that impressive to anyone, but even if you do care about that stuff, the voting badges are probably the easiest to game.

Comment: but if we vote for deserving one then i don't think so this is possible to earn these 2 badges as it is hard to do 40 votes for deserving one in a day

Comment: @BunkerBoy Wait until you get access to the Close Votes review queue. Many questions in there deserve a downvote. And that queue never empties, there's always another really bad question in there... :-S

Comment: The point is there is no way for anyone to know how or why you voted so no one is going to be impressed

Comment: I guess if one looked at "Upvoted without answer" and at the bountied questions, one could find a number of questions that deserve an upvote. And by looking at the questions of respected members of the community.

Comment: I think you should change "most" to "some", especially for any badge that is not "bronze" ... As a sample: how about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal?userid=307988) badge, did you really earn that one by just "gaming"???

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you could "game" that badge by voting on the question and answer with sock puppets. I don't know, I can't remember all the badges off the top of my head but I'd guess you can game most in some way

Comment: In that case I suggest you also mention those "sock puppets" in your answer ... While you're adapting your answer, how about you also include something about "tag"-badges: pick any tag-badge on any SE site that you can "game" ... IMO you cannot ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens the question was about two specific badges; I'm not going to go through and list how you can cheat the system to get all the different badges

Comment: OK for me. Though I was not talking about "cheating". All I want to say is that I disagree with your "***you can game most badges***".

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens "game" in that context basically means "cheat"

Comment: Hm, really? Curious to see then how my suggested edit is going to be perceived ...

Comment: Ok well I'm not sure how you can disagree and be "not talking about cheating" at the same time. To be honest I'd probably go as far as saying you can game *any* badge

Comment: [My suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50334) got rejected ... interesting ... Just in case: feel free to overrule those rejections from the reviewers (as OPer you should be able to do so).

Answer (score 2):

Badges aren't "good" or "bad". Some are rarer than the others, but they're generally just

1. to encourage certain good behaviors,
2. to shape your site browsing habits in the early stage.

Unless you have a special person or authority in mind that arbitrarily assigns the label "good" to some badges, Stack Exchange doesn't have a way to show a badge is different from other badges, other than designating its bronze-, silver- or gold-ness.

---

As a guy who hangs out here often, if you ask me what badges I prefer to see on a profile, it's "Marshal", "copy editor" and "Steward". "Illuminator" is good as well, but a person with that many answers has most probably received their reward in terms of reputation points.

Then again, there are an awful lot of robo-reviewers (people who review without paying enough attention), bad, uneducated flaggers and trivial, unnecessary edits just to game a badge.

The wisest of us all are people who wouldn't judge you when they haven't seen you ask or answer anything. Badges don't tell you much.

---

I see you're another user who's interested in gaining badges. Here's what the finish like for your hype would look like:

You either will

- just burn out really fast without gaining the badges you aimed for, like most of the people, or
- make some really silly mistake that you wouldn't feel like continuing, or
- start not caring about gaining badges, but instead genuinely helping with the moderation, and realizing **this is what you should've done in the first place**, because now badges would be coming in without you hunting for them.

Trust me. Most of the more experienced users here looked to hunt badges at one point or the other, and I was one of those. And once they started sticking around, they saw hunting badges and rep isn't the best way to earn them.

They're a good incentive, but not good as the main incentive.

Comment: _""Illuminator" is good as well"_, yes - and has been awarded so rarely that the lack of it doesn't tell you anything. It's the least awarded badge on SO save for the mod badges, on math.SE there have been more mods than recipients and it's never been awarded on SF or Arqade and only one each on SciFi and SU (very quick sample of some sites).

Comment: @ben well, if the OP is going for rare badges, Illuminator is a bit too high to aim.